# Чёрно-белый экран

Tags: windows-10, ноутбук

Я сидела за ноутбуком и легонько стукнула по клавиатуре (возле угла) и экран стал чёрно-белым. Что делать?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не относится ни к программированию, ни к администрированию.

Comment: @AK, я не согласен, что вопрос надо закрывать.

Comment: @AK, и вообще, 4 голоса вопрос получил ещё при плохой формулировке, так что переоткрываю.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится к программированию или системному администрированию.

Answer (score 6):

В windows 10 есть сочетание горячих клавиш, которое делает экран черно-белым: 
ctrl+windows+c.
Нужно повторить это сочетание.

Comment: А если Линово можно тоже так нажать?

Comment: @Даша, это сочетание клавиш не ноутбучное, а Windows-овое. Поэтому оно сработает на любом компьютере с установленной Windows 10.

Comment: Спасибо большое помогло здоровья вам!!!!!!

Comment: @Даша, тогда ответ прими нажатием на галочку слева от него.